# Drawing multiple moving objects

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I'm currently working on an iOS game where, long story short, I need to draw a lot of moving cubes - approximate maximum of 200 per frame. Emphasis on *moving* because yes, I have indeed Googled away for hours on this topic and have yet to find a suitable solution for fast, efficient drawing of multiple objects where their position updates every frame.

Through my endless amounts of research on this subject most seem to mention VBOs, however I'm not sure this would suit my case where the position of every object changes every frame.

I'm using OpenGL 1 at the moment - I have working code and on generation 3/4+ devices (the ones which support OpenGL 2, ha) it runs at a reasonable framerate - however when testing on my (old, yes) 2nd-gen iPod touch, it is very sluggish and essentially unplayable.

My code comprises of a static array of vertices for a 'cube' and an array containing the position and colour of every cube. My game logic loop updates the position of every cube in the array. At the moment I'm looping through the cube array, calling glTranslatef and glDrawArrays for every cube. From what I've read this is very inefficient, however I'm completely confused as to how you would optimise it. Any ideas?

(maybe I shouldn't be aiming for old, discontinued iOS devices but given my belief that my code is incredibly inefficient, I figure it'll help my future endeavours regardless if I find a way to address this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such simple objects I would make one big VBO say 200 Objects * NrVerticesPerCube, put all the data interleaved Vertex,Normal,UV,Vertex,Normal,UV, etc.

I do something similar in a keyframe animation of a beaver in my game, I start with something like this:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vboObjects[vboGroupBeaver]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboObjects[vboGroupBeaver]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, beaverVerts*8*sizeof(GLfloat), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
vbo_buffer = glMapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES);
NSString *path;
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beaver01" ofType:@"bin"];
NSFileHandle *model = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
float vertice[8];
int counter = 0;
while (read([model fileDescriptor], &vertice, 8*sizeof(float))) {
    memcpy(vbo_buffer, vertice, 8*sizeof(GLfloat));        // 0
    vbo_buffer += 8*sizeof(GLfloat);
    counter++;
}
glUnmapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

This creates my VBO buffer with the correct size (in this case 8 * sizeof(GLfloat) wich is 3 Verts, 3 Normals and 2UV), and copies the first keyframe to the buffer, you could do the same with you initial object positions, or just leave that and compute latter...

Then in each frame I do interpolation between 2 keyframes for each vertex of my beaver, and just make one draw call, this is very fast for the 4029 vertices my beaver has, and works at 60FPS on my iPhone 3G.

For you doing only gltranslates it would be even simpler, just add the values of x,y,z to each vertice of each cube.

You would update it like this:

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboObjects[vboGroupBeaver]);
    GLvoid* vbo_buffer = glMapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES);
```

Bind the vbo buffer and mapit to a buffer var.
Calculate the stuff you want on a temp var.

```
            memcpy(vbo_buffer, currentVert, 6*sizeof(GLfloat));        // 0
            vbo_buffer += 8*sizeof(GLfloat);
```

Copy it and update buffer to next object, repeat until all objects updated...
You could also do all the updates in a seperate array and copy the whole array, but then you would be copying extra info that usually doesn't change (normals and UV). Or you could not use interleaved data and copy that...

```
        glUnmapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

Unmap the VBO buffer

```
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 8*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL));
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 8*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL+3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT,8*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL+6*sizeof(GLfloat))); 
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, beaverVerts);
```

Setup your draw call, and draw it all...

If you need to rotate objects and not just gltranslate them, you will need to add some matrix multiplications along the way...

EDIT **

ok, making a gltranste by hand is actually very easy (rotation, etc is a bit trickier).

I'm using a an interleaved plane drawed using TRIANGLE_STRIP instead of triangles, but the principle is the same.

```
  float beltInter[] = {
0.0, 0.0, 0.0,             // vertices[0]
0.0, 0.0, 1.0,             // Normals [0]
6.0, 1.0,                  // UV [0]
0.0, 480, 0.0,             // vertices[1]
0.0, 0.0, 1.0,             // Normals [1]
0.0, 1.0,                  // UV      [1]
320.0, 0.0, 0.0,           // vertices[2]
0.0, 0.0, 1.0,             // Normals [2]
6.0, 0.0,                  // UV      [2]
320.0, 480, 0.0,       // vertices[3]
0.0, 0.0, 1.0,             // Normals [3]
0.0, 0.0                   // UV      [3]
  };
```

So this is interleaved vertex, you got vertex then Normals then UV, if you're not using textures substitute UV for color.

The easiest way is to have an array with all the objects inside (made easy if all your objects are the same size) and make the position updates after draw (instead of in the middle of the opengl frame), better still make a seperate thread, create 2 VBOs update one of them while drawing from the other, something like this:

- Thread 1 OpenGL DrawFrom VBO0
- Thread 2 Game Updates, update positions on internal array and copy to VBO1, set Var saying VBO1 yes ready (so thread 1 only changes from drawing to VBO1 when all the updates are done).
- Thread 1 OpenGL DrawFrom VBO1
- Thread 2 Game update, same thing but update VBO0
- continue with same logic

this is called double buffering and you use it to garanty stability, without this sometimes your game logic will be updating the VBO while the graphics card needs it and the graphics card will have to wait, resulting in lower FPS.

Anyway, back on topic

to make the equivalent to gltranslatef(10,20,30) just do:

```
 int   maxvertices = 4;
 float x = 10;
 float y = 20;
 float z = 30;
 int   counter = 0;
 int   stride  = 8;                // stride is 8 = 3 x vertice + 3 x normal + 2 x UV change to 3 x color or 4 x color depending on your needs
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboObjects[myObjects]);
 GLvoid* vbo_buffer = glMapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES);
 while (counter < (maxVertices*8)) {
      beltInter[counter]   += x;   // just sum the corresponding values to each
      beltInter[counter+1] += y;  
      beltInter[counter+2] += z;
      memcpy(vbo_buffer, currentVert, 3*sizeof(GLfloat));  // again only copy what you need, in this case only copying the vertices, if your're updating all the data, you can just do a single memcpy at the end instead of these partial ones
      vbo_buffer += stride*sizeof(GLfloat);     // forward the buffer
      counter += stride;         // only update the vertex, but you could update everything
 }
 glUnmapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

 glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, stride*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL));
 glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, stride*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL+3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
 glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT,stride*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)((char*)NULL+6*sizeof(GLfloat)));   
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, maxVertices);
```

Of course the update values doesn't have to be the same for all the objects, infact using a base array like this you can update all the info as you go along and just have the routine to copy it to VBO when needed.

All this was written from memory on the fly, so there maybe dragons :-)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still quite confusing to me. I would have to calculate and update the VBO in my game object loop, correct? I should point out that my 'generic cube' is an array of 72 vertices (something like "1.0,0.0,0.0,...") - in order to update this in a single array for a VBO, I would need to calculate the would-be-glTranslate offsets for every vertex for every cube based on the cubes position, right? And how would I be able to store the colour data?

Comment: Yes, you would update the VBO in the game loop, 72 vertices for each cube so you're looking at 14400 vertices ? That's a bit of a bump from my 4029 vertices, but my main game draws a lot more vertices on a 3G, it could still work. Yes, but to make a translate all you have to do is sum the values to each vertice, that's very fast, I'm using interpolation in mine wich is much worse. Colour data should be interleaved, I'm using textures, you would have coulou data instead of UV mapping, and call the apropriate glcolorpointer...

Comment: Thanks again. Hopefully my last question, I was setting this up and looked at my cube vertices (http://puu.sh/f3Yz) and uh.. how exactly would I 'sum the values to each vertice' in order to set the correct position? For example, if I wanted to translate X +5 and Z +10, what would I have to change for each vertice?

Comment: Gave a complete example in the reply above :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could optimise quite a bit by sticking all the coords for all your cubes in a single array, and drawing it with a single glDrawArrays  call.

I'm not sure why you'd want to split up the cubes into separate arrays, except maybe because it makes your data structure more elegant/object oriented, but that's the first place I'd look at making an improvement.

Dump the cube coordinates in one big array, and give each cube object an index into that array so that you can still keep your update logic fairly compartmentalised (as in, cube n owns the coordinates in the range x to y and is responsible for updating them, but when you actually draw the coordinates you run glDrawArrays directly on the centralised coord array instead of looping through the cube objects and rendering them individually).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I meant with the multiple arrays is that one is a static array defining the vertices for a generic cube, and then I have my main array which contain the data for the cube objects. They are each looped, glTranslate'd to their position and then my 'generic cube' is drawn. How would I be able to combine all of the vertices into a single array?

Comment: I also realised a potential problem with this method - my cubes have different colours. At the moment I use glColor in the loop that draws each cube, how would it be possible to have all of this data in a single array?

Comment: You can add a separate colour array in addition to your vertex array. It would mean specifying the colour for each vertex instead of once per cube, but I don't think there's a significant penalty for that.